# Structure in Django tutorial does not match match my strucuture

Tags: django, frameworks

Starting a new project and realized that the structure for the tutorial and my structure do not match. It looks like a directory was created for the myproject and a directory AND a file were created for myapp... I don't understand. Is this correct?

Tutorial structure shows:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
```

My structure shows:

```
mysite/
    myapp
        myappp
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@NinaPy**,  Your directory structure  seems to be correct but there exist an issue.

Please follow the steps:

***1)*** Go to your directory where you want to keep your project. Example--myproject folder

**cd myproject**

***2)*** Now you are within your desired folder.  run the command from **CLI**(Command Line Interface)

**django-admin startproject mysite**   //mysite is the project name

it will create

1 directory[**mysite**] and 1 file[**manage.py]**

***3)*** Now if you want to create an app: Go to **mysite** directory because **manage.py** exist in there.

**cd mysite**

run the command from **CLI**

**python manage.py startapp myapp**

It will create **myapp** in  same level.

```
myproject/
   mysite 
   manage.py 
   myapp
```

If you use the **CLI** then you are quite safe for folder directory and file structure. Do not try it to do manually unless you need some extra files.

Please have a look on here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Comment: I see what I did.  I created the app outside of the directory  (cd mysite) somehow.  Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

your can run python manage.py startproject to create a new project

Answer (score 0):

yes its correct
before run type on terminal(enter the directory mysite)

```
cd mysite
```

then run

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py startapp appmane
........
..........
```